# Convert PDF to Word strategy

Tags: java, apache-fop

So, I'm struggle with a problem, I'm trying to convert a PDF with a lot of tables and styles to a DOC, I created this PDF with apache FOP.
I tryed a lot of converters, apache poi (cant keep the styles, spaces and tables)

Anyone can help me or suggest a solution ?

Comment: As you _created_ the PDF, wouldn't it be easier to use the same input to create the doc file (or maybe another format Word can open) too?

Comment: The DOC generated by the FOP is very basic, he dont know how to deal with tables and images very well.